# Mis à part vs. apart from

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, synonymes, locutions

My question is the following: can **mis à part** be used both for expressing "inclusion" and "exclusion" as is the case with the english **apart from**. What I mean is that in English it would be possible to say both:

Inclusion: *Apart from Germany, they also visited Italy and Austria*

Exclusion: *Apart from Friday, I'll be in London during the whole week*

But what about in French? Would it be correct to say:

*Mis à part l'Allemagne, ils ont aussi visité l'Italie et l'Autriche* (meaning that they visited both Germany, Italy and Austria)?

*Mis à part vendredi, je serai à Londres pendant toute la semaine* (meaning that except for Friday, I will be in London)

Comment: Nice scope of question and explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *mis à part* or just *à part* are usable in both contexts.

Should you want to insist on the inclusive or exclusive status:

> En plus de l'Allemagne, ils ont aussi visité l'Italie et l'Autriche

> Je serai à Londres toute la semaine sauf vendredi.
> Vendredi exclu/excepté, je serai à Londres toute la semaine.

Comment: A l'oral, "à part" et surtout "sauf" sont quand même énormément plus utilisés que "à l'exclusion de"

Comment: @XouDo Pas faux, j'essaie autre chose...

Answer (score 3):

Native speaker. Yes, you can use the expression *mis à part* to convey either inclusion or exclusion in French just like you do in English.

Examples of inclusion:

> Mis à part le risotto, avez vous d'autres plats végétariens au menu?

> Mis à part Sophie qui a déjà demandé un croissant, qui d'autre veut un croissant?

Examples of exclusion:

> Mis à part le risotto qui est végétarien, tous nos plats contiennent de la viande.

> Mis à part Sophie qui n'a pas faim, tous les enfants veulent un croissant.

Back to your example, *Mis à part l'Allemagne, ils ont aussi visité l'Italie et l'Autriche* , the word "aussi" gives it the inclusive meaning, which is usually reinforced by context:

> En Allemagne ils ont vu Berlin, la Forêt Noire et le lac de Constance. Mis à part l'Allemagne, ils ont aussi visité l'Italie et l'Autriche.